# Creating a dictionary from a dat file

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to build a program that manages your phone contacts, ie. lets you print your contacts, search for a contact, add a contact, delete a contact, etc. The program should create a dictionary based on data stored in a dat file, which is formatted as follows:

alex smith,646-528-3280,jsmith@stern.nyu.edu

jane doe,347-238-3220,jgonzalez@stern.nyu.edu

....

Based on this, I want to create a dictionary in Python where the key is a string containing a name and the corresponding value is a list holding two strings: [phone number, email address].

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm just getting started learning Python and am a total noob :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `defaultdict` in python from collection for creating dict data structures with values of different types.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

store = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.dat', 'r') as FH:
    for file in FH.readlines():
        line = file.strip()
        try:
            name,phone,email = line.split(',')
        except ValueError, err:
            print "Record: ", line
            raise Exception("Failed while unpacking. Not enough arguments to supply.")
        store[name].extend([phone,email])

pprint(store)
```

Here is a sample to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file line by line, split each line into 3 fields, then create the dictionary:

```
d = {}
with open("mydatafilename", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split(',')
        d[fields[0]] = fields[1:]
```